# Find the count and indexes of occurrences of a string

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose given a string, how can I get the character, no. of occurrences and occurrence indexes in a single query?

Eg : Consultant

Character no of occurrences index:

```
C   1   1
O   1   2
N   2   3,9
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE to split it apart and then aggregate:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), null) as c, convert(varchar(max), 'Consultant') as rest, 0 as lev
      union all
      select left(rest, 1), stuff(rest, 1, 1, ''), lev + 1
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select c, count(*), string_agg(lev, ',')
from cte
where lev > 0
group by c;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=dc583325b3e9ffb2eb5e0b5052a489e5) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Nice solution, one can add the asked for count too using `select c, count(lev), string_agg(lev, ',')`

Comment: You can even keep the sorting besed on the input,  `order by min(lev)`.  This seems not that exiting, but the output of [string_spit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) is not defined, and when the order of items in a string is needed, than this CTE can give the answer.